# Shell scripting for login

Tags: linux, scripting, shell

Is there any way to login to another machine specifying the password in the script itself??

SSH-keygen wont work for me so i need to specify it in the script

```
  #!/bin/sh

    ssh root@201.1.192.21 mysqldump -uroot -pxxxxxx > backup/a.sql
```

Comment: if not use user keys maybe using host keys should be usefull, you can also specify key with -i option

Comment: @Ignacio:Please see this http://serverfault.com/questions/200708/ssh-keygen-problem.I have problems in doing ssh-keygen

Answer (score 0):

You can use [expect](http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/56066).

Comment: I dont want to use expect.Script calling a script :)

Comment: Out of interest: why is that a bad thing? If that is disallowed don't boot your system because that is exactly how init works.

Comment: @Reese there are many timeout problems associated with expect script

Comment: @Rajeev: Because there are security issues with passing passwords on the command line, `ssh` doesn't accept them as arguments. Using keys or `expect` is the way it's done.

Comment: @Dennis I am learning about the various ways of automating interactive tasks through shell these days and still not sure which methods are secure. How does using expect do this securely? Can you confirm if expect would be the correct secure solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594698/using-a-variables-value-as-password-for-scp-ssh-etc-instead-of-prompting-for-u? Thanks

Comment: @Reese - can you too check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594698/using-a-variables-value-as-password-for-scp-ssh-etc-instead-of-prompting-for-u please? I just want to confirm if expect would be the correct and secure solution for me